# Vim - delete until (inclusive) character in multiple lines

Tags: vim, vi

I have this code:

```
def foo(c: Char) = c match {
    case 'a': 'B'
}
```

My cursor is on the space after `=`. I want to delete everything until, including, the `}`. How can I do that?

Can I do the same where the cursor is anywhere on the first line? Anywhere in the block (and place the cursor after the `=`)?

Comment: `v`-> `j`->`j`->`d` may do the job

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
d/}/e
```

does the job.

`d/}` deletes *until* the `}` but adding the `/e` flag moves the cursor on the last char of the match, effectively deleting everything between the cursor and the `}`, *inclusive*.

Using visual selection works too, in a slightly more intuitive way:

```
v/}<CR>d
```

Comment: `/e` doesn't seem to work with the IntelliJ IDEA vim plugin

Comment: The question is about Vim.

Comment: is that a vim command or a shortkey ? cause d} shortkey deletes a paragraph and :d/}/e doesn't really do anything.

Comment: There's no concept of "shortkey" in Vim. `d}` is an operator, `d` for "delete", followed by a motion, `}` for "to end of current paragraph": it deletes everything between the cursor and wherever `}` would get you. `d/}/e` is the same operator, `d`, followed by a different motion, `/}/e`, for "search for the next `}` and leave the cursor on the `}`.

Answer (score 27):

Try with this: `d%`.

The `d` is for delete and the `%` moves between braces.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
d}
```

This deletes one paragraph forward.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve something like this with the [EasyMotion plugin](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion).