# delete word, wih quotes, in vim

Tags: vim

if I have the following text:

```
['abc']
```

and the cursor on the first quote.

- dw gives me `[abc']`
- d2w gives me `[']`
- d3w gives me `[`

so, how can I delete `'abc'` and keep `[]`

Comment: You mean like, :s/'abc'//, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: quite often I am in a situation where I just want to remove elements in a list; so I can have a list like ['one', 'two', 'three'] and I'm trying to find the least keypress way to remove some element in the list. Using a search is not good in this context since I'd have to type more. What makes it not work is the quote around the string, without quotes a simple 'dw' or 'dwx' (for the comma) would work

Comment: @ggorlen, yes it does. I guess mine's a dup, I didn't find it when I was looking for a solution

Comment: I like `di[` or `di]` (mnemomic, "delete inside square brackets") for this kind of thing. Bonus, you can repeat the same command in a different spot with just one keystroke, the "dot" `.` (which also is true of `ct]` and `df'` etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for single lines:

1. "Cut til" with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> or "delete til" with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>. More info is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/64840/853475) (you can delete backwards, yank til, etc).
2. "Delete find" (delete through target): <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>
3. Visual line/find: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. Verbose but gives some agency to adjust as needed.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384494/delete-word-wih-quotes-in-vim/65384656#comment115596005_65384494) you mention you have a multi-element list and want to remove an item. The contents of the element matter; I usually proceed in an ad-hoc manner, using combinations of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> or the visual line/find with <kbd>w</kbd> or small adjustments near the target to clip out the element in addition to techniques above.

For example, if your list is `['one', 'two', 'three']` and your cursor is over the first `'`, you can use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to produce `['two', 'three']`.

---

Other useful threads:

- [Delete everything between two brackets in Vim, including newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209074/delete-everything-between-two-brackets-in-vim-including-newlines/40209145)
- [Vim - delete until (inclusive) character in multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953741/vim-delete-until-inclusive-character-in-multiple-lines/19953810)
- [In Vim, how can I delete everything between quotes including the quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843099/in-vim-how-can-i-delete-everything-between-quotes-including-the-quotes)

Comment: exactly what I needed. I didn't know the 'cut til' functionality, I will go through that in the doc. thanks!

Comment: Answer mentined above will work only if you have cursor at the first character. Correct answer should be da' as mentiond by @filbranden. It'll help you repeat it with dot in other cases as well, and your cursor can be anywhere inside or above quote

Comment: I agree--that's a repeat of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843099/in-vim-how-can-i-delete-everything-between-quotes-including-the-quotes) which is canonical so I'll vote to close as a dupe. Nonetheless, `df[space]` removes the trailing comma and space for [this special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384494/delete-word-wih-quotes-in-vim/65384656?noredirect=1#comment115596005_65384494) so it's nice to know both. OP @Thomas should feel free to move the checkmark to that answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
d i [
```

To delete everything inside square brackets

Comment: `d i ]` works as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `da'`.

The `a'` text object selects the text under the cursor surrounded by single quotes, including the quotes themselves.

See [`:help a'`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#aquote):

> "a quoted string". Selects the text from the previous quote until the next quote.

This text object is quite smart, if there are multiple quoted strings in a line, Vim will figure out which pairs make out strings. Vim can also recognize escaped quotes inside a string (the default escape character is `\`, but even that you can configure through the `'quoteescape'` option.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit counterintuitive at the start, but you can use "search&replace" for these type of tasks.

In vim, you are looking for `:s` [Vim WiKi](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace), find the string 'abc' and replace it with empty string.

You should use something like Don mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

While @ggorlen's answer about `d` `f` `space` is great, some people might find it beneficial to use a mapping which works regardless of where the cursor is position on the word, something like:

```
nnoremap [something] :normal vf,oF'xx<CR>
```

Will remove the 'one' element in the below example no matter where on the one it is.

```
['one', 'two', 'three'] => ['two', 'three']
```